# MongoDB Making my schema structure less relational

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, schema

I've been chugging along building my mongodb but I  just realised I haven't actually taken the time to think of the best strategy for that and I might be misusing the nosql structure and building a more traditional relational structure. I'm building a community forum and so far the collections I have are as follows:

```
User - stores all user settings/data such as email, name, password, date joined, email/notification preferences, etc..

Profile - stores handle, gender, user location, forum rank, interests and then several arrays containing id's of things like an array of follower id's, array of post ids, array of upload id's, array of club id's, array of posts the user has liked, etc.

Posts - stores comment data, creator user id, category and then has an array of id's to uploaded files and an array of user id's for likes.

Uploads - GridFS schema to use when uploading files
```

What I'm now realising that all these arrays of id's of things in other collections are behaving a lot more like a relational db, especially the Profile schema which is basically just a collection of id's to other collections. Can you give any advise on the type of db I'm creating and how to improve it? For example, should I have a single User schema which contains all posts and profile data directly inside it rather than storing id's to a separate schema in a different collection? As I'm using this project to learn, I'd really like to continue using mongodb rather than moving to something like MySQL.

Comment: I would argue that you do not need anything more than `UserProfile` & `Posts` collections. I am not following the `Uploads` schema idea but if these are files uploaded to posts then they should be an array in `Posts` probably. `User` & `Profile` should be one model as I see no reason to separate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Akrion eluded too in the comment above, the first step was to combine the User and Profile schemas. The other thing that I wasn't thinking about before was what information gets called together. The new UserProfile schema shouldn't contain things like comments/posts/uploads/likes as those things will be better off existing as part of the Post document. My problem was thinking that having a record of those things in my UserProfile would optimise the retrieval of those items when I needed them but I just ended up bloating my UserProfile schema. It's no different searching the posts collection by creator rather than by an ID taken from the UserProfile document. The Upload documents are now no longer GridFS schemas but are instead records of files in the file system but that is less relevant to my original question.